# Activate spring profile in EJB

Tags: spring, ejb, profile, interceptor

I'm using Spring profile for my webapp's and it works great.

I activate those profile in web.xml files like this :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>myProfile</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But I'm stuck with my MDB.

I bootstrap spring from my MDB with the SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor and it works but I don't known how to activate my profile for this MDB.

I've tried to add an env-entry but it doesn't seem to work :

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>spring.profiles.active</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>myProfile</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Can someone help me?

Is there a way to activate profile via the beanRefContext.xml (used by the interceptor) ?

Thank you

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

instead of looking to do it from the context params, you can try setting it from JNDI.  (Spring looks for active profiles in JNDI on startup by default.)  it looks for a `String` array (comma delimited string or an array) and it's looking for it under the key `spring.profiles.active`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply! Can you briefly tell me how to do this?

Comment: setting JNDI properties is very dependent on the JNDI provider.  which container are you using for your MDB? (JBoss, WAS, etc.)

Comment: Weblogic version 10.3.3

Comment: i'm personally not familiar with WebLogic but you would need to look at how to add a Resource object to the JNDI provider that is a `String[]`

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround with EJB Interceptors :

```
public class ActivateSpringProfileInterceptor {
@Resource(name = "spring.profiles.active")
    private String springProfile;

    @PostConstruct
    @PostActivate
    public void activateProfile(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        if (springProfile == null || springProfile.isEmpty()) {
            throw new EJBException("No spring.profiles.active env-entry is found in DD for this EJB !");
        }

        System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", springProfile);

        try {
            ctx.proceed();
        }
   }
```

}
and I put this in my ejb-jar.xml

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor>
      <interceptor-class>ActivateSpringProfileInterceptor</interceptor-class>
      <env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>spring.profiles.active</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>${spring.profiles.active}</env-entry-value>
      </env-entry>
    </interceptor>
  </interceptors>
```

It works but I would prefer not changing System variables...

Any other workaround?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that could cause conflict between 2 apps if they share the same virtual machine... Any other solution?